Disable 2 simple websites using old Apache version 2.4.37
I have RedHat 8 server with Apache/2.4.37 running on it and we're hosting 4 vhost simple websites. I'd like to disable 2 of those 4 website while keep the other websites running.
I tried many things but nothing works really.. If i shutdown httpd service, of course will take all 4 websites down.
I cannot find this command "a2dissite" anywhere on my system (I guess due to the old Apache version i have)
Any help would be greatly appreciated

This question is similar to: How to a2ensite and a2dissite on Red Hat?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think i was able to disable the specific website by editing httpd.conf and use the following:
IncludeOptional conf.d/vhosts/websitename.conf


On RHEL8 check /etc/httpd/conf.d/ for .conf files, that contain the config for the two websites. Rename the files for the sites you want to disable and reload the apache service.

I tried to rename those ".conf" files & restarted httpd but i'm still able to access the sites

The a2dissite and a2ensite commands just change your /etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory.
Delete the symlinks in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled for the vhosts you want to disable and restart Apache.
To recover, create symlinks from the vhost configuration files in /etc/apache2/sites-available to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled and restart.

This doesn't work on Red Hat.

I don't have these 2 commands .. i don't even have '/etc/apache2' directory

How about /etc/httpd?
